# Problem using NSURLRequest to POST data to server

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, http

I create an `NSURLRequest` to post my data in the iPhone application to a server to proceed the PHP script. My PHP script is look like this.

```
<?php
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];

    $link = mysql_connect("localhost", "fffasfdas","Nfdsafafs") or die ("Unable to connect to database.");
    mysql_select_db("muradsbi_mydatabase") or die ("Unable to select database.");

    $sqlstatement= "INSERT INTO dbname (name,email) VALUES ('$name','$email')";
    $newquery = mysql_query($sqlstatement, $link);
    echo 'thanks for your register';
?>
```

and my `NSURLRequst` is created like below.

```
NSString *myRequestString = @"&name=Hello%20World&email=Ohai2u";
NSData *myRequestData = [NSData dataWithBytes: [myRequestString UTF8String] length: [myRequestString length]];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL: [NSURL URLWithString: @"http://www.google.com/"]];
[request setHTTPMethod: @"POST"];
[request setHTTPBody: myRequestData];
NSData *returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest: request returningResponse: nil error: nil];
```

However, this site is unable to get the data from this application and save it to the database, but I know it was connected succussfully because my application is able to get the response data from the server. I don't know whether my variable name is declared in the wrong way or others issues. How can I fix it?

Comment: Also, you aren't releasing your memory... and you are missing some ";" characters.

*PLEASE* always post your actual cut/pasted code.

Comment: cut/paste actual code makes SQL injections more likely ;)

Comment: use another library/collection to handle ur web requests for an easier time! http://allseeing-i.com/

Answer (score 53):

You should remove the leading `&` in `myRequestString` and the problem is likely that the correct `content-type` header is not being sent. Try adding a call to

```
[request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"content-type"];
```

You should also not pass `nil` for error, so you can see what the client thinks is going on.

Unrelated, but your PHP code is open to [SQL injection attacks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

Comment: @superfell-- just so I make sure I'm not a complete moron, is that because he's using unsanitized inputs for name and email, or is there something else I'm missing?

Comment: Yes, it takes random input and put it in a sql string to execute without any escaping or other checking.

Answer (score 7):

It should be noted that ...

```
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithBytes: [myRequestString UTF8String]
                              length: [myRequestString length]];
```

... is very bad and can cause vague errors. With UTF8 there is zero guarantee that the number of bytes in your encoded string is the same as the number of characters in your string.

So instead, you should simply use:

```
NSData *data = [myRequestString dataUsingEncoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
NSString *name = [[NSString alloc]initWith String: @"Hello World"];     
NSString *email = [[NSString alloc]initWith String: @"Ohai2u"];     
NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://somedomain.com/sendMail.php?name=%@&email=%@", 
                           [name stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding],
                           [email stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:urlString];

    NSURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

    NSData *urlData;
    NSURLResponse *response;
    urlData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:urlRequest returningResponse:&response error:nil];
    [url release];
```

just dont forget to **release** the strings

set the headers in the PHP script

Comment: This is GET. Question related to POST request.