# PHP/MySQL Web Service for iOS App

Tags: php, objective-c, sql, xcode

I am trying to get an app of mine to communicate with a database that is hosted on a server.  I did some reading and found that one of the better ways to do this was to use a php as an intermediary step.

I have a .php file that can takes in data, converts it into queries, then writes it to the database.

I am just wondering how to get my app to talk to the .php.

Comment: By making requests to it, using, for example, [`NSURLConnection`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLConnection_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

Comment: [What Have you Tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: I haven't tried anything yet.  Well I have the whole app written besides for the last step with the php.  I like to read before trying to code anything.  Thank you for the link Radu.

Comment: possible duplicate of [iPhone PHP integration](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1311933/iphone-php-integration)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the most basic: Make a http request to the php file.

Of course you will probably want authentication, and CRUD operations.

Answer (score -2):

You can use the [ASIHTTPRequest library](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/) instead of NSURLConnection to save yourself some work.

Comment: ASIHTTPRequest is unfortunately deprecated and no longer supported/maintained. There are other suitable alternatives though such as [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/).

Comment: In fact, I haven't heard about AFNetworking, thanks for the link!
Was searching for replacements for ASIHTTPRequest recently..