# Passing text to a php POST method iphone sdk

Tags: php, iphone, objective-c

I'm developing an iPhone application and I need to send some information to an url from a textview and 2 texfields, using the HTTP POST method. (to, subject, message). How do I do it? I understand it is something with `NSURLRequest`, but I didn't find anything that could actually help me. So if you could please include a clarifying code example, I would really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recently wrote a subclass of `NSMutableURLRequest` to make form POSTing a lot easier.  It's on github:  http://github.com/davedelong/CHFormRequest

You use it like this:

```
#import "CHFormRequest.h"

CHFormRequest * r = [[CHFormRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://example.com/myForm.php"]];

[r setValue:@"test" forFormField:@"field1"];    
[r setFile:@"/Users/example/Desktop/myFile.txt" forFormField:@"file"];

NSHTTPURLResponse * response = nil;
NSError * error = nil;
NSData * d = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:r returningResponse:&response error:&error];
[r release];
```

Comment: thank you for your link, but I get 2 errors at compiling: 

error: 'kUTTagClassFilenameExtension' undeclared (first use in this function)
AND
error: 'kUTTagClassMIMEType' undeclared (first use in this function)

Can you help please?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you find

[iPhone sending POST with NSURLConnection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2071788/iphone-sending-post-with-nsurlconnection)
[Problem using NSURLRequest to POST data to server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/330060/problem-using-nsurlrequest-to-post-data-to-server)

helpful.