# How can I use NSURLRequest to submit a login form which isn't coded in PHP?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, forms

I am trying to submit a login form (which can be viewed [here](http://www.dhsb.org/Mobile)) in my app, but there is no PHP file whatsoever - so how can I code something similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/330060/problem-using-nsurlrequest-to-post-data-to-server), just without the PHP and just literally inputting text into the text fields in UIWebView and then submitting the data to the destination URL?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't matter if the server is PHP or any other technology. You can use `NSURLRequest` to submit it.

Anyway, if for some reason you need to use the `UIWebView` approach, you'll need to fill the form and submit it using JavaScript with `stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString`.

Add something like this in `-[UIWebViewDelegate webViewDidFinishLoad:]`: (adjust jQuery paths to your case)

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView 
{
    ...
    NSString *result;
    result = [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"$('#username-box').val('the-user-name');"];
    result = [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"$('#password-box').val('secret');"];
    result = [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"$('#submit-button').click();"];
    ...
}
```

Comment: Great, thank you - very very appreciated! How can I use the contents of a UITextField to put into the username field and then another UITextField to put that text into the password field? I tried doing it but failed :(

Comment: Once you get the UITextField value, I guess something like this will work: [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"$('#username-box').val('%@');", fieldValue]];

Comment: oops, doesn't work, I was testing it out with previous code. Nothing happens :(

Comment: do you have another solution please? :-)

Comment: Nop. The solution I proposed works. Maybe you can ask a different question, with details about the problem you have, and we'll see if we can answer it.