# Beginner in html and objective-c, nsurlconnection and html values

Tags: html, objective-c, nsurlconnection

I'm currently working with objective-c and have run in to a problem concerning javascript. I am connecting to a website through an iphone app and my goal is to login to a html form (Login.jsp)

```
<label class="login_label">Username</label>
     <input autocomplete="off" type="text" value="" name="ssusername" size="20" maxlength="50" />

     <label class="login_label">Password</label>
     <input autocomplete="off" type="password" name="sspassword" size="20" maxlength="20" value=""/>
```

I am trying to make a `NSUrlConnection` to this site in objective-c but the concern is this: If I enter

```
 https://www.login.com/Login.jsp?ssusername=%@&sspassword=%@, username.text, password.text
```

It will only enter the enter the password in the html form. And when I look at the javascript I suspect it has something to do with the value in the username html code being value=""

**My question:** Is it possible to, without changing the html code (as I don't have access to it) make a `NSUrlConnection` passing username and password and retrieving the answer from this html form, or if anyone know why the username wont show when the adress is entered as above?

Comment: can you show full HTML form code instead of label ? What is the action method ? Post or GET method ? https://www.login.com/Login.jsp?ssusername=%@&sspassword=%@ is only for get method. Need to more detail of your HTML form method.

Answer (score 0):

I think, login method may use POST method and your NSURLConnection is using get method.

You can check at [POST with NSURLConnection - NO JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8979317/post-with-nsurlconnection-no-json).

Comment: tanks! I will check it out!

Answer (score 0):

It depends on server side. You can't really change input field value via GET parameters -- it's server-side job. 
You can execute JS code to enter username and password and then click login button via UIWebView's [stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIWebView/stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString%3a) function or you can check this site/server documentation for some authentication methods and then use them (like @saturngod suggested).