# NSUInteger should not be used in format strings?

Tags: objective-c

Here's my code in all it's glory:

```
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Total Properties: %d", (int)[inArray count]];
```

Which gets me an Xcode 5.1 warning:

```
Values of type 'NSUInteger' should not be used as format arguments; add an explicit cast to 'unsigned long' instead
```

Ok so I'm confused. The value really is a 32-bit int, and I cast it to a 32-bit int. So what is this NSUInteger it's complaining about (the count I assume) and why doesn't this cast fix it?

Comment: Are you sure that the line produces a warning? I use they cast to int all the time myself, and I never get an error. Just checked it in Xcode 5.1 with a simple example.

Comment: To hopefully forestall confusion of future readers: this warning appears (or not) depending on the architecture for which you are compiling.

Answer (score 108, accepted):

NSUInteger and NSInteger are different lengths on 32-bit (int) and 64-bit (long). In order for *one* format specifier to work for *both* architectures, you must use a long specifier and cast the value to long:

```
Type    Format Specifier    Cast
----    ----------------    ----
NSInteger    %ld            long
NSUInteger   %lu            unsigned long
```

So, for example, your code becomes:

```
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Total Properties: %lu", (unsigned long)[inArray count]];
```

There is very little work to do, really, because Xcode's Fix-It feature will do this for you automatically.

Comment: Thanks matt! Works *almost* like a champ, the almost being because the fix-it doesn't seem to be fixing it.

Comment: Well, your original int cast may have confused it. I just did a huge number of fixes along these lines in my book code (last four or five commits at https://github.com/mattneub/Programming-iOS-Book-Examples), and Fix-It got most of them right. But some of them had to be done by hand.

Comment: However, NSInteger/NSUInteger is the same length as long/unsigned long on both architectures. So why is the cast necessary?

Comment: @matt: My premises are correct. If you think they are wrong please point out which statement you think is wrong and what you think is wrong with it.

Answer (score 47):

It is also possible to use the "z" and "t" modifiers for CPU-independent format strings, e.g.

```
NSInteger x = -1;
NSUInteger y = 99;
NSString *foo = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"NSInteger: %zd, NSUInteger: %tu", x, y];
```

Answer (score 9):

The underlying type of `NSUInteger` changes based on the platform: it is a 32-bit unsigned integer on 32-bit platforms, and a 64-bit unsigned integer on 64-bit platforms.

In the [*Platform Dependencies* section on of the *String Programming Guide*](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/Strings/Articles/formatSpecifiers.html) Apple suggests that you do the following:

> To avoid the need to use different printf-style type specifiers depending on the platform, you can use the specifiers shown in Table 3. Note that in some cases you may have to cast the value.
>
> For `NSUInteger` use format `%lu` or `%lx`, and cast the value to `unsigned long`.

Hence your code needs to be changed as follows to avoid the warning:

```
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Total Properties: %lu", (unsigned long)[inArray count]];
```

Comment: The same with `unsigned long`. So why is the cast necessary?

Comment: @user102008 Because `NSUInteger` is platform-dependent.

Comment: So is `unsigned long`

Comment: @user102008 But `unisgned long`  matches `%lu` on all systems, while `NSUInteger` may match either `%lu` or `%llu`, depending on the system.

Comment: You said "it is a 32-bit unsigned integer on 32-bit platforms, and a 64-bit unsigned integer on 64-bit platforms". That's the same with `unsigned long`.

Comment: @user102008 It's a coincidence. Sizes of `NSUInteger` and `unsigned long` are controlled by separate entities (the makers of the Cocoa library vs. the makers of the Objective-C compiler). `%lu` is guaranteed to always match `unsigned long`; there is no such guarantee for `NSUInteger`, because it is owned by different people. If Cocoa makers decide tomorrow that `NSUinteger` should be 32 bits on all platform starting with the next release, they can 100% do it. This would break formatting code without the cast.

Answer (score 0):

You could also try using NSNumber methods:

```
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Total Properties: %@", [[NSNumber numberWithUnsignedInteger:[inArray count]] stringValue]];
```