# Scan for images in website - Xcode

Tags: html, objective-c, xcode, image, finder

I am making an app which will give me the latest news, and the image. I achieve the text bit by making a scanner like this.

```
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
    /* set headers, etc. on request if needed */
    [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22671347/nsuinteger-should-not-be-used-in-format-strings"]];
    NSData *data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:NULL error:NULL];
    NSString *html = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSScanner *scanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:html];
    NSString *token = nil;
    [scanner scanUpToString:@"<p>" intoString:NULL];
    [scanner scanUpToString:@"</p>" intoString:&token];
    int length = 3;


   token = [token substringFromIndex:length];
    textView.text = token;
```

Now I was wondering if I could use the same type of code to scan the website to find the first image and put it an image view. Also it don't have to be same type of code , post what ever you know and any method.

Summary is.

Want a piece of code that will scan a webpage, pick up the first image and place it in a image view.

Thanks for the people who take the time to help me.

THANKS AGAIN!!!
BYE!!!

Comment: What did you try? You could start by search for `<img` and go from there.

Comment: I tried that. Not working as expected

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NSScanner its not a HTML parser only intended for scanning values from NSString object. If you doing the odd scan you probably could get away with it, but it doesn't seem like...

The CORRECT approach is to use [Libxml2 library](http://xmlsoft.org/) included in Xcode which is only written is C which doesn't have any Objective-C/Swift wrapper. Libxml2 is the XML C parser and toolkit developed for the Gnome project. Alternatively i would recommend using open-source project such as [HTMLReader](https://github.com/nolanw/HTMLReader). Its a HTML parser with CSS selectors in Objective-C and Foundation. It parses HTML just like a browser and is all written in Objective-c.

**Example (using HTMLReader):**

```
HTMLDocument *document = [HTMLDocument documentWithString:html]; // get your html string
NSLog(@"IMG: %@", [document firstNodeMatchingSelector:@"img"].textContent); // => image returned here
```

To find images just change the tag to < img > and your set!!

IF your using Libxml2 take a look at [HTMLparser.c header file](http://xmlsoft.org/html/libxml-HTMLparser.html) to parse and retrieve HTML ltags

Comment: Thanks but, I am not here to set a default value it is a changing value. Kinda like an RSS feed. Thanks for helping anyway. If you can , can you tell me how to get the source of the image using Xcode at least. Thanks would be help full.

Comment: where is the tag. yes i am new. and i am 13. lol would be helpful if you could edit the code and actually write how to do it.

Comment: firstNodeMatchingSelector method looks for the first tags inside your html string, set that to img and that will return your image code.

Comment: Ok so I checked the frame works there are many  with Libxml2 which one is it , libxml2.2, or 2, or many others. Cause when i copy the code it comes with error

Comment: libxml2.dylib library, the above snippet is an example with HTMLReader open-source project.