# retrieve data posted with NSRequest on an PHP file on server

Tags: php, objective-c, nsurlrequest

Here is the situation :

- I have rented a server where php 5, apache2 are up and running.
- I'm doing HTTP POST request on my iOS App using NSMutableURLRequest and NSURLConnnection.
- I'm sending data as following :

  ```
  NSMutableDictionary *postDictionnnary = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:@[@"login",username,password]
                                                                              forKeys:@[@"type",@"username",@"password"]];
  NSData *requestBodyData = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:postDictionnnary];
  request.HTTPBody = requestBodyData;
  ```

  1. Is this the right way ?
  2. On my server, in my php file, where do i get those datas ? $_REQUEST seem empty.

Thanks !

Comment: Answer here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/330060/problem-using-nsurlrequest-to-post-data-to-server

Answer (score 0):

try adding a method to `request`

`request.HTTPMethod = @"POST"`

In your php file, you should be able to retrieve your data using `$_POST['key'];`